# How to make Rust compiler resolve import from std?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I'm using the Rust 0.6 compiler for mingw32.  I'm able to compile small programs that import from "core", but not from "std".  Here is a transcript showing a trivial example and how I am compiling it:

```
$ cat prog.rs
use std;
$ rustc.exe prog.rs
error: failed to resolve imports
prog.rs:1:4: 1:8 error: unresolved import
prog.rs:1 use std;
              ^~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How do I get rustc.exe to resolve the import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to load the external crate via `extern mod std;`, and then you can `use` modules within that crate, or just use them directly qualified by `std`, e.g.

```
extern mod std;
use std::bigint;

fn main () {
    bigint::BigInt::from_uint(1);
    std::semver::parse("1.2.3-alpha1");
}
```

[There is more information here](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#using-other-crates).